# TypeScript Generics: Create a generic map

Tags: typescript

Exercise from a TypeScript course:

> Create a map using TypeScript Generics. The key is always a string.
>
> The value can be a string ***or*** a number. It has to work with ***both*** types.
>
> It's got to have the following methods:
>
> - Creating a new key-value pair : **setItem(key: string, item: T)**
> - Retrieving values : **getItem(key: string)**
> - Remove all items : **clear()**
> - Display all key-value items : **printMap()** "

Here my uncompiled TypeScript code:

```js
// -- THE ACTUAL IMPLEMENTATION --------------------------
class GenericMap < T extends number | string > {
  private items: object[]

  constructor() {
    this.items = [];
  }

  setItem(key: string, item: T): void {
    let tmp = {};
    tmp[key] = item;

    this.items.push(tmp);
  }

  getItem(key: string): T {
    let ret = null;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
      let curr = this.items[i];

      if (curr[key]) {
        return curr[key];
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  clear() {
    this.items.length = 0;
  }

  printMap() {
    this.items.forEach((item) => {
      let key: string[] = Object.keys(item);

      console.log('{ "' + key[0] + '": ', item[key[0]], '}');
    });
  }
}

// ------- JUST TESTING --------------------
const numb = new GenericMap < number > ();
numb.setItem('alpha', 7);
numb.setItem('beta', 14);
numb.printMap();
numb.clear();
numb.printMap();

const strMap = new GenericMap < string > ();
strMap.setItem('color', 'Blue');
strMap.setItem('height', '54 cm');
strMap.printMap();
// ---------------------------------------------
```

The compiled code as a live-demo:

```js
class GenMap {
  constructor() {
    this.items = [];
  }
  setItem(key, item) {
    let tmp = {};
    tmp[key] = item;
    this.items.push(tmp);
  }
  getItem(key) {
    let ret = null;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
      let curr = this.items[i];
      if (curr[key]) {
        return curr[key];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
  clear() {
    this.items.length = 0;
  }
  printMap() {
    this.items.forEach((item) => {
      let key = Object.keys(item);
      console.log('{ "' + key[0] + '": ', item[key[0]], '}');
    });
  }
}
const numb = new GenMap();
numb.setItem('alpha', 7);
numb.setItem('beta', 14);
numb.printMap();
numb.clear();
numb.printMap();
const strMap = new GenMap();
strMap.setItem('color', 'Blue');
strMap.setItem('height', '54 cm');
strMap.printMap();
```

It works fine. But I guess there a better ways to solve these exercise.

Especially my getItem-method has become rather long.

**Has someone an idea to solve the exercise in a more elegant way?**

**What do you think about my idea of storing objects within an array?**

Looking forward to reading your answers and comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to understand the way `getItem()` works in its current implementation. I even thought that there's a bug (after rereading the code, I see I was wrong about it).

- Let's start with obvious. The `ret` variable; can be safely removed.
- The whole search loop is counter-intuitive to me, because each element in the `items` array is an object which stores a `value: T` under a different `key: string`. If you really want to use `items: object[]`, you'd rather have it's elements declared as `{ key: string, value: T }`. And this immediately moves us to the next point that answers your question about the choice of the type of the backing object.
- An entity that stores key-value pairs in TypeScript and JavaScript is `Object`. Why not use it instead? I don't know if using `Object` is disallowed by your real problem definition.

  If it is not disallowed, it would be *very natural* to define items as an `Object` and wrap it into a `GenericMap` which exposes the API your problem requires.

  However, if it *is* disallowed, you should not use it in the `setItem()`'s code (`tmp[key] = item;`) as well. Because it's technically same kind of a "cheat" anyway.

Below is the code that is built around an `Object` instead of an `Array`. As you can see, pretty much all of the operations are now "pass-through" one liners. Including the `getItem()` which you said got pretty long in the original code.

---

```
class GenericMap<T extends number | string> {
  private items: { [key: string]: T } = { };

  setItem(key: string, item: T): void {
    this.items[key] = item;
  }

  getItem(key: string): T {
    return this.items[key];
  }

  clear(): void {
    this.items = {};
  }

  printMap(): string {
    const itemsAsString = Object
      .getOwnPropertyNames(this.items)
      .map(key => `'${key}': ${this.getItem(key)}`)
      .join(", ");
    return `{ ${itemsAsString} }`;
  }
}
```

A few TypeScript style side notes:

- `private items: { [key: string]: T } = { };`

  - If we initialize our fields in-place (as a part of their definition), we don't need an explicit `constructor()` which makes code shorter.
  - `{ [key: string]: T }` is a compiler hint that will -- at least in some cases -- help detecting incorrect usages of the field
- I personally have never seen the whitespaces around `<` and `>` when used with generics, e.g. `GenericMap < T extends number | string >`. It's not TypeScript idiomatic I believe.

Hope, it helps.

Comment: One more thing to mention, enabling `strictNullChecks` is always a good idea.

Comment: (As I realized this wouldn't point out the possible error in this code, `this.items[key];` can be undefined and should be typed as such)